# Is it possible to use Harmony (ES6) with JSXTransformer.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-harmony

I've had great luck using React's [JSXTransformer.js](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html#jsx) to develop using JSX in the browser:

```html
<script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/jsx">
/** @jsx React.DOM */
...
</script>
```

To reduce boilerplate, I'd like to use some of the features from Harmony, e.g. [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Facebook's [JSX Compiler Service](http://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html) has a harmony checkbox which transforms ES6 to more traditional JS:

```js
var f = v => this.props[v];
// becomes var f = function(v) { return this.props[v]; }.bind(this);
```

Is it possible to enable this transformation with the in-browser JSX?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This feature [was added](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/17/react-v0.11.html#jsx) in React v0.11. Instead of `type="text/jsx"`, you set `type="text/jsx;harmony=true"`. For example:

```html
<script type="text/jsx;harmony=true">
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var f = v => v*v;
console.log(f(2));  // logs 4
</script>
```

Comment: Note: as of React v0.12, the `@jsx` pragma [is unnecessary](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/16/react-v0.12-rc1.html#the-jsx-pragma-is-gone).

Comment: what is "@jsx pragma"