# Reactjs - the spread operator giving error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use the spread operator in react.js  but  getting the error `Unexpected token ...` in Chrome.

I am getting an error at the line 3 in this code:

```
var Btn=React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var { className, ...other }=this.props;
        return (<a  {...other} className={joinClasses(className,"btn")} href="#" >{this.props.children}</a>);
    }
});
```

and using JSXtransformer.js for the compiling the JSX code.

What am I doing wrong that is causing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome does not support the `...` token yet.

See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Browser_compatibility) for supported browsers (or see below).

**Spread operation in array literals**

- Chrome - 46
- Firefox - 16
- Internet Explorer - No
- Opera - No
- Safari - 7.1

**Spread operation in function calls**

- Chrome - 46
- Firefox - 27
- Internet Explorer - No
- Opera - No
- Safari - 7.1

**Spread operation in destructuring**

- Chrome - No
- Firefox - 34

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25876089/982075) to see how to set up the JSX Transformer to use "ES6 Transforms".

Comment: This is JSX code not JS so I thought that the `...` symbol is implemented by react and not by the browser. Is that not so?

Comment: JSX transforms your html-ish stuff into function calls on the React.DOM namespace, but thats about it. So no

Comment: You can see the generated js here: https://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html

Comment: On that page (the jsx compiler) there's an option to `Enable ES6 transforms  (--harmony)` - that changes the code to something without a `...` - I think that's what I need.

Comment: Figured it out - all I had to do was this :  use `<script type="text/jsx;harmony=true">` instead of just `<script type="text/jsx">` to enable the `harmony` mode. Thanks